# Custom PXE install / How do installers work?

Tags: system-installation, iso, pxe

I have set up a PXE server for my network, from where I serve the default Ubuntu ISO image. Running the installation leads the user through the (graphical) Ubuntu installer. I'd like to modify this step (other packages installed by default, some more configuration options at install time).

How would I go about this, providing a custom ISO for the system I want by default?

Do I need my own installer?

Even if not required, I'd love to understand how installers work, how they are executed inside the ISO, and if there is material available for further study?

PS: I have deliberatly not tagged this question as Ubuntu, because I'm more interested in the general concept.

Comment: It’s hard to give a generalized answer for all Linux distros, because there is no one uniform installer for all distros.  Debian/Ubuntu has debian-installer (d-i) which can be automated with a preseed file (Ubuntu also has autoinstall).  RHEL/Centos/Fedora has Anaconda and can be automated with a kickstart.  I don’t know enough about other distro options to comment.  Perhaps you could deploy an image that has something like ghost4linux to deploy pre-configured images?

Answer (score 0):

You need a so-called preseed configuration file and inject that into the installer.

See also: [Ubuntu Installation Guide -- B.2. Using preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html)

Comment: Newer Ubuntu server can also use the annoying hard to google “autoinstall” (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall)